# Execute grails formRemote automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, forms, grails, onload

I am using the grails formRemote `http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/formRemote.html` to biuld my forms. Is there any way to submit the form automatically on pageLoad. I've tried using Javascript techinques but it seems that JS refreshes the whole page... I stil want to keep the formRemote functionallity which refreshes only a part of the page using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test.

Here is my controller:

```
package test

class NothingController {

    def index() { }

    def submit() {
        render "Hello ${params.name}"
    }
}
```

And here is my GSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta name="layout" content="main" /><g:javascript library='jquery' /></head>
    <body>
        <g:formRemote id="myForm" name="myForm" update="updateMe" url="[controller: 'nothing', action:'submit']">
            Name: <input name="name" type="text" value="John Doe"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Go"/> 
        </g:formRemote>
        <div id="updateMe">this div will be updated</div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#myForm').submit();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to have a javascript library like jquery, so I placed it in the head.  Otherwise, the form will not behave in AJAX.

Comment: It seems like to only trick is in the selector... I am using Dojo

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with Javascript. Simulating the buton click...

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     if(buttons[i].type == 'button' && buttons[i].value == "Search") { //make sure you have the right button
          buttons[i].click();
          break; 
     }
  }
```